# page.php not working in my website

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

[image]

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function `woodmart_get_content_class()` in `/home/u9766796/public_html/wp-content/themes/woodmart/woodmart2/page.php`:17 Stack trace: #0 `/home/u9766796/public_html/wp-includes/template-loader.php`(106): `include()` #1 `/home/u9766796/public_html/wp-blog-header.php`(19): `require_once('/home/u9766796/...')` #2 `/home/u9766796/public_html/index.php`(17): `require('/home/u9766796/...')` #3 `{main}` thrown in `/home/u9766796/public_html/wp-content/themes/woodmart/woodmart2/page.php` on line 17

I have shopping website but I'm new to Wordpress and i downloaded All in One SEO plugin even though I have Yoast SEO on my site after that my site crashed and became inaccessible even if I removed the plugin from cpanel. I now get this `page.php` problem. How can I solve this problem and reopen my site?

Comment: I believe your question will be better answered at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/.  But a common method is to deactivate all plugins via the backend so that the admin interface becomes accessible. Then you can enable all except those responsible for the crash. Solution would be executing the query UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'a:0:{}' WHERE option_name = 'active_plugins'; for WordPress versions greater than 2.9. I found this from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624551/wordpress-deactivate-a-plugin-via-database. CAUTION: backup db and test on local/dev before trying on live.

Comment: I again emphasize that you can post your query on wordpress.stackexchange.com before trying the solution I have mentioned earlier.  Just in case you try the solution I had mentioned, exercise extreme caution by backing up your DB and testing on the local machine. I am not a WordPress expert.